# Fill according to the entered value

Tags: javascript, html

I tried change the coordinates in css, but the level does not stick to the tube and it also breaks the look on image.
i need that gradation was like this:
100 - full, 75 - average, 50 - half, 25 - Low, 0 - Empty

```js
document.getElementsByName('water-level')[0].addEventListener('change', updateWaterLevel);

function updateWaterLevel() {

  var fractionFull = this.value / 100;
  var dy = (1 - fractionFull) * 150;
  document.getElementById("tubeLiquid").setAttribute("transform", "translate(0," + dy +")");
}
```

```css
.item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  
  #tubeLiquid {
    background-color: #74ccf4;
    clip-path: polygon(40% 24%, 38% 28%, 38% 32%, 38% 86%, 38% 91%, 40% 94%, 44% 96%, 57% 96%, 60% 94%, 62% 91%, 62% 86%, 62% 33%, 62% 29%, 60% 25%, 59% 24%);
  }
  
  #bottleMask{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    clip-path: polygon(40% 24%, 38% 28%, 38% 32%, 38% 86%, 38% 91%, 40% 94%, 44% 96%, 57% 96%, 60% 94%, 62% 91%, 62% 86%, 62% 33%, 62% 29%, 60% 25%, 59% 24%);
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" value="" name="water-level" />
<div class="item">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <defs>
        <mask id="bottleMask" fill="white">
          <path d="M0,0h300v300H0V0z M89,68h122v147H89V68z" />
        </mask>
        <clipPath id="liquidClip">
          <path d="M89,68h122v147H89V68z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <image width="300" xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/HGFQYTj/bottle.png" />
      <path id="tubeLiquid" fill="#74ccf4" d="M0,0h300v300H0V0z" clip-path="url(#liquidClip)" mask="url(#bottleMask)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my previous answer, your current clip-path/mask structure is slightly complicated.

Actually, only the css clip-path has an effect on your graphic.

Currently you're just moving your progress/fill bar via `translate()`.
Your clip-path has relative units and will also move:

```css
svg{
  overflow:visible;
  width:20em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


.item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  

  .clipped{
    clip-path: polygon(40% 24%, 38% 28%, 38% 32%, 38% 86%, 38% 91%, 40% 94%, 44% 96%, 57% 96%, 60% 94%, 62% 91%, 62% 86%, 62% 33%, 62% 29%, 60% 25%, 59% 24%);
  }
```

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
        <rect class="clipped" x="0" y="58" width="200" height="233"  fill="#74ccf4" />
        <rect class="clipped" x="115" y="58" width="70" height="233"  fill="#74ccf4" transform="translate(0 50)" />
    </svg>
```

### CSS clip-path: Add a transparent `<rect>`

You can circumvent the aforementioned scaling issue by adding a `<rect>` filling the entire viewBox:

```js
let inputWaterLevel = document.querySelector('[name=water-level]');
let heightLiquid = +tubeLiquid.getAttribute('height');
let yLiquid = +tubeLiquid.getAttribute('y');
let liquidPercent = heightLiquid/100;

inputWaterLevel.addEventListener('input', updateWaterLevel);

function updateWaterLevel() {
  let value = +this.value;
  
  // calculate new height
  let h = liquidPercent * value;
  let y = yLiquid + (heightLiquid-h);
  
  // update height and y offset
  tubeLiquid.setAttribute('height', liquidPercent * value )
  tubeLiquid.setAttribute('y', y )

}
```

```css
svg{
  overflow:visible;
  width:20em;
}


.item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  

  .clipped{
    clip-path: polygon(40% 24%, 38% 28%, 38% 32%, 38% 86%, 38% 91%, 40% 94%, 44% 96%, 57% 96%, 60% 94%, 62% 91%, 62% 86%, 62% 33%, 62% 29%, 60% 25%, 59% 24%);
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="50" name="water-level" />
<div class="item">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <rect x="118" y="68" width="64" height="228" rx="20" ry="20" />
    </clipPath>

    <image width="300" xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/HGFQYTj/bottle.png" />
    <g class="clipped">
      <rect id="clipBG" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="transparent" />
      <rect id="tubeLiquid" x="115" y="58" width="70" height="233" fill="#74ccf4" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

### Native SVG `<clipPath>`

```js
let inputWaterLevel = document.querySelector('[name=water-level]');
let heightLiquid = +tubeLiquid.getAttribute('height');
let yLiquid = +tubeLiquid.getAttribute('y');
let liquidPercent = heightLiquid/100;

inputWaterLevel.addEventListener('input', updateWaterLevel);

function updateWaterLevel() {
  let value = +this.value;
  
  // calculate new height
  let height = liquidPercent * value;
  let y = yLiquid + (heightLiquid-height);
  
  // update height and y offset
  tubeLiquid.setAttribute('height', liquidPercent * value )
  tubeLiquid.setAttribute('y', y )

}
```

```html
<p><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="50" name="water-level" /></p>
<div class="item">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="150">
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <rect x="118" y="68" width="64" height="228" rx="20" ry="20" />
    </clipPath>
      <image width="300" xlink:href="https://i.ibb.co/HGFQYTj/bottle.png" />
        <rect clip-path="url(#clip)" id="tubeLiquid" x="115" y="58" width="70" height="233"  fill="#74ccf4" />
    </svg>
  </div>
```

This approach has the advantage, you can draw/position your progress elements as they would appear at 100% progress.
Now you can change their height relative to 100%:

```
let heightLiquid = +tubeLiquid.getAttribute('height');
let liquidPercent = heightLiquid/100;
```

The new height of the progress bar would be

```
  let h = liquidPercent * value;
```

But we also need to calculate a new y value to align the progress bar to the bottom

```
let yLiquid = +tubeLiquid.getAttribute('y');
```

### `<line>` as progress element

Using a `<line>` element for the "tubeLiquid" element can simplify the javaScript function even further as it allows us to set the `pathLength` attribute to 100.

```js
    waterLevel.addEventListener('input', e => {
      let value = +e.currentTarget.value
      tubeLiquid.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${value} 100`)
    })
```

```css
line{
transition:0.5s
}
```

```html
<p><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="waterLevel" name="water-level" /></p>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="150">
        <clipPath id="clip">
              <rect x="115" y="55" width="69" height="235" rx="20" ry="20" fill="red" />
        </clipPath>
        <image width="300" href="https://i.ibb.co/Mhfwtxp/image-removebg-preview-1.png" />
        <line id="tubeLiquid" clip-path="url(#clip)" pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="50 100" x1="149.5" y1="290" x2="149.5" y2="50" stroke="#74ccf4" stroke-width="80" />
      </svg>
```

Comment: thank you so much! this is indeed a much better solution and I will look into it thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, an `<input type="range">` determines the percentage values of a linear-gradient.

***Details are commented in example***

```js
// Reference the <input>
const input = document.getElementById("fill");
/*
Bind #fill to the "input" event so that it reacts immediately to
all user interactions with it.
*/
input.oninput = fillBottle;
// Called whenever the user adjusts #fill 
function fillBottle(e) {
  // Reference the <html>
  const root = document.documentElement;
  // Reference <output id="percentage">
  const perc = document.getElementById("percentage");
  // Get the value of #fill and then change it from a string to a number
  let base = parseInt(this.value);
  // Apply this formula to derive a inverse percent number
  let mod = 100 - base + "%";
  // Display the percentage with <output id="percentage">
  let view = base + "%";
  // Pad the value of #percentage with 6 zeros
  perc.value = view.padStart(4, "0");
  /* 
  Change the value of --empty on :root -- this will change the
  percentage values in .water styles
  */
   root.style.cssText = `--empty: ${mod}`;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --empty: 50%/* Initial value of <html> variable -- the value
  of the variable applies anywhere in the styles as var(--empty)  */
  ;
  font: 2ch/1.15 Consolas;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/*
This <div> sits beneath everything -- it's background-image is a
gradient of white and blue. it's only visible through the trans-
parent part of .bottle.
*/

.water {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 103px;
  height: 365px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white calc(var(--empty)), #46CBFF calc(var(--empty)), white 95%)/* This background's perc-
  centages are equal to --empty which is driven by the input of
  <input id="fill"> */
  ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bottle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 104px;
  height: 360px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background=color: white;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/SBRwQTQ/bottle-mask.png)/* This image is transparent within the bottle shape
  border and opaque elsewhere. The image sits on top of evrery-
  thing */
  ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#fill {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#percentage {
  font-size: 3rem
}
```

```html
<div class="water">
  <div class="bottle"></div>
</div>

<input id="fill" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">
<output id="percentage">050%</output>
```